# CoreData - Can not add relation after fulfilled fault

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am working with two managed object contexts; a read only frontend contexts and another backend context that is used to manipulate objects.

In the code block, the second assert fails. If I comment out the first assertion, the second one will be ok. So, I have narrowed it down a bit. It seems that when I have accessed the property productAccess, so the fault is fullfilled(?), I can not add additional access objects to the user, even if I do a new fetch in frontend context.

```
- (void)testAddingAccesses{
     [self addAccessToUser];
     [self addAccessToUser];

     UserMO *newFront = [UserMO getUser];

     STAssertOperation([newFront.productAccesses count], 2u, ==, @"Should be two!!");    

     [self addAccessToUser];
     UserMO *another = [UserMO getUser];

    STAssertOperation([[another.productAccesses allObjects] count], 3u, ==, @"Should be three!!");    
}
```

**More details**

```
[self addAccessToUser]
```

Picks up the one and only UserMO and adds an AccessMO (in backend context), then saves background context.

```
[UserMO getUser]
```

Will return the one and only user in frontend context.

Why does not changes get reflected after the first time I access the frontend productAccesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

If you are using two context, you do need to refresh the object to get the most recent changes in store.

```
[frontendContext refreshObject:user mergeChanges:YES];
```